# I want to know if my code is thread-safe

Tags: android, multithreading, view

I have a code like this, which makes a anonymous thread
everytime the loop goes. And the length of cityArray is 17.

```
for(int i=0; i<cityArray.length; i++)
{
    final int finalI = i;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setMarkerIcon(cityArray[finalI]);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And it calls the setMarkerIcon method, which runs the getBestMarkerItemfromArrayList, then runs runOnUiThread to update view.

```
public void setMarkerIcon( final String city ){
final MarkerItem markerItem = getBestMarkerItemfromArrayList(city);
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "run: ");
        if(markerItem != null){
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.back_level3)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onResourceReady: " + map.getMarkers().size() + "__" + city);
                            for (int i = 0; i < markerOptions.length; i++) {
                                if (map.getMarkers().get(i).getData().equals(city)) {
                                    map.getMarkers().get(i).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(city, bitmap)));
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

The code works well, and there seems to be no problem at the moment.
But I just want to make sure that I am using the thread correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: When you want to run so many things on the UI thread anyway then why do you need to spawn so many threads to do so each time?

Comment: Will it be better if I just remove my threads and just run it on the UI Thread?

Comment: Unless `getBestMarkerItemfromArrayList` takes a long time (long being relative), yes.